# "c'est" or "il est" for use with adjective

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> Je ne joue pas au tennis parce **que c'est** trop difficile pour moi.
>
> Je ne joue pas au tennis parce **qu'il** est trop difficile pour moi.

Which one is correct, or both? If both are correct, is there a difference in meaning?

Similarly,

> J'ai une table. Elle est grande.
>
> J'ai une table. C'est grand.
>
> J'ai une table. C'est grande.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first series, the second one does not work. Only the first one is possible. That is probably because *ce* refers to the whole *jouer au tennis*, to which cannot really be assigned an *il* or *elle*. It's more of an "abstract" thing than required for *il* or *elle*.

In the second series, only the first one is possible. The other two are broken. It's the reverse here: *table* is pretty clearly a feminine noun for a concrete thing. So *elle* not only works, but is even required.

Let's try this:

> Je monte sur la table. Elle est grande.
>
> Je monte sur la table. Ça me fait du bien.

Both are possible. In the first example, *elle* clearly refers to the table. In the second example, *ça* on the other hand refers to the action of *monter sur la table*.

Comment: Interesting. Why is the correct pronoun *ce* in the first series but *elle* in the second series? The two series are very similar to each other.

Comment: Yes, they are - and I noticed you asked the question in that very smart fashion :-) I am currently at a loss for an explanation, but these cases are pretty black and white, there is no gray area here.

Comment: I think I got an explanation, which I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. But couldn't *difficile* in the first series only refer to *le tennis*. I think we can say *le tennis est difficile (pour moi)*, can't we?

Comment: @user11550 It would be only be possible in this kind of sentence: *Je ne joue pas **ce** tennis là parce qu'il est trop difficile pour moi.*

Comment: Ce can’t refer to *monter sur la table* much like ça?

Comment: @Blaszard *Ce* can refer to *monter sur la table* but must be used with the verb *être* in that case. *Je monte sur la table. C'est bien pour moi.*